# Create infinite longlist selector in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I have a Long List Selector. when page loading first then it has 10 items in the list, when user scroll down the list and when he reach to the bottom of the list then I want to add 10 items to the list.

I tried lot of methods to catch the end of the scroll but can't find any event for it in WP8.

Answer (score 2):

You can use event ItemRealized on Longlistselector or
Try this
http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector.aspx

Comment: I tried it. but it doesn't work for me. because I dont know what is the last item, it's depends on search query. So how can I recognize the ItemRealized event? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic. The trick is same that you tried. I.e. You need to listen to a specific event and load the next 10 item. For a detail code example see  [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e)